# Search form in two Regions?

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

New to Drupal, trying to wrap my mind around the Blocks concept.

Am I right in concluding that I cannot have the SearchForm on the right side (sidebar second) for one ContentType, and on the left side (sidebar first) for another ContentType?

I'm talking standard 7(.17) with no extra modules or PHP "hacks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Drupal will only allow you to specify the placement of blocks once. To achieve what you're after you'll need to look into using a contributed module like [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) or [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

Personally used Context a fair bit in the past. It's pretty powerful but relatively simple to use.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  So this google-found statement: "enable multiple region selection in the block admin interface in Drupal 7.0 or via module" - is just false (have looked for it for hours) ?

Comment: I believe it is false. Drupal can only store one block location in the database (if I recall correctly). I'd give Context a look as it will enable you to specify blocks based on content types. We have tended to use it as a complete replacement to the default blocks admin as it gives much greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

[This module](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock) allows you to create several instances of a block, so you can duplicate a block and put the duplicates on other regions.

Comment: I actually ended up using multiblock also : )